# VaultTrackBy is giving all the states involved in the transaction

Tags: corda

I have a transaction where I output two different type of states. There is 1 state of the first type and about 5 states of other type. I have a code to track the vault by the first state type but when I send the transaction over the tracker returns all 6 states. See secreenshot

[image: VaultTrack issue]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was filed [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3336). It was fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3276). The fix will be included in Corda 4.